# Searching deeply nested element in the entire document

Tags: jquery

I need to select a form input, that sometimes is inside an iframe, other times is inside a frameset. I think it changes according to the account operation I'm logged in (the website is not mine).
When inside an iframe, I'm doing:

```
$("#iframeApp").contents().find("#formInput").val();
```

But when inside the frameset, I didn't found a correct way to select it, so far I have this:

```
$("frameset frame parentFrame form").each(function() {
 alert(this.name);
});
```

I think it's not working because the form is nested like:

```
<frame src="..." name="parentFrame" id="parentFrame">
    #document
    <html>
    <frameset>
      <frameset>
         <frame>
          #document
           <html>
             <body>
               <form ...>
</frame>
```

Ok, so my idea is: maybe is possible to search for the form ID, in the entire document, iframes, frames, anything, I tried:

```
$(document).find("#formInput");
```

But didn't returned anything... Is there anyway to select this form, and consequently the form input, in a simpler way, without the need to specify the entire parents nodes for this? And this way work in both cases (when inside an iframe, or a frameset)?

Comment: $('#formInput") didn't work? can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: don't work, it was the first thing I tried... I think its because is inside an iframe/frameset... Not sure... The fiddle, is hard because the website is complex, and not mine as I said, so not sure how I would copy that for a fiddle...

Comment: if you have nested frames, then you will have to do a custom function that do what you do for one frame.. with recursion probably. Check if you have a iframe in your content, then use find or contets() and call the function again

Comment: Can you give me a 'pseudo' function to do that?

Comment: if you have access to code in the frame...could use postMessage API to communicate between the windows. Each frame is a different window and different dom